# Multiple Univariate regression (lm) using a for loop but problem with missing values. (Using R studio)

Tags: r, regression, missing-data, univariate

I want to execute this code that work well when there is no missing values :

```r
results_table <- NULL 

for (i in 1:3) {
  for (j in 1:4) {
    y <- Data[[paste("Y", i, sep = "")]]    
    x <- Data[[paste("X", j, sep = "")]]   
    regression <- lm(y ~ x, na.action = na.omit)  
    
    result_table <- as.data.frame(coef(regression))
    rownames(result_table) <- NULL  
    
    result_table <- cbind(Model = paste("Y", i, "X", j, sep = ""), result_table)
    
    result_table$t_value <- summary(regression)$coefficients[ , 3]             
    
    
    result_table$R2 <- summary(regression)$r.squared
    results_table <- rbind(results_table, result_table)
  }
}

kable(results_table, "html", full_width = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling()


write.xlsx(results_table, "Tableau des résultats.xlsx")
```

Since I have a dataset with missing values for my X, my results _table is giving two different regression for each pair of Y and X...as you can see :

```
Model   coef(regression)    t_value R2
Y1X1    3.4696056   5.2944460   0.0502490
Y1X1    0.0387244   0.7967998   0.0502490
Y1X2    3.9619072   11.7370893  0.0009698
Y1X2    0.0027125   0.1079289   0.0009698
Y1X3    3.7690610   7.0310259   0.0125282
Y1X3    0.0154775   0.4061187   0.0125282
Y1X4    3.1764475   10.3196793  0.3763734
Y1X4    0.0612605   2.5765790   0.3763734
Y2X1    4.1314063   3.8939545   0.0772674
Y2X1    0.0788739   1.0024226   0.0772674
Y2X2    5.0330531   8.7751280   0.0056833
Y2X2    0.0111840   0.2618950   0.0056833
Y2X3    4.6933359   5.3766990   0.0241810
Y2X3    0.0352227   0.5675761   0.0241810
Y2X4    4.5929518   8.0655550   0.0882175
Y2X4    0.0453782   1.0316397   0.0882175
Y3X1    5.6005118   228.2063229 0.0156123
Y3X1    -0.0007940  -0.4362557  0.0156123
Y3X2    5.5861209   438.3518058 0.0087679
Y3X2    0.0003091   0.3258004   0.0087679
Y3X3    5.5939316   282.3214782 0.0030456
Y3X3    -0.0002807  -0.1992830  0.0030456
Y3X4    5.5713199   403.1526816 0.1377492
Y3X4    0.0014151   1.3256354   0.1377492
```

Can you please help me with that ? I tried specifying na.action, but it doesn't work. Ideally, i just want to do my regressions ignoring the missing values and only using the existing values as i want to avoid imputation with a stochastic method...is that possible ?

My data looks like this :

```
Années  Y1          Y2          Y3         X1         X2           X3          X4
1997    3.963468451 5.183829287 5.593129455             
1998    4.253845002 5.172830464 5.591625596             
1999    4.031846905 5.1869224   5.592468831             
2000    3.595760906 4.750252996 5.584059807             
2001    4.154317291 5.118948623 5.598643243             
2002    3.774063139 4.775448021 5.580539653             
2003    3.95796166  5.18286509  5.584611758             
2004    4.032551592 5.156931881 5.584742622             
2005    3.918859703 5.450326495 5.593116615 14.15070974 15.16366872 14.18995694 14.82719648
2006    3.949859207 5.371408921 5.590567504             
2007    3.929588499 5.121684176 5.587730194 13.32888473 14.55418168 12.86568128 14.43830522
2008    3.885425751 5.311795386 5.58567571  13.30468491 13.07335578 14.72306759 12.05626035
2009    4.111628205 5.600820253 5.595435825 13.34724453 9.881508626 12.61153773 
2010    3.81854987  5.260332949 5.586646584 13.94621784     14.20785842 9.23443792
2011    4.175661237 5.017529711 5.599481149 14.42157535 14.77465676 14.63373979 14.17248136
2012    4.152413396 4.917988628 5.590977301 12.9241345  12.4511591  14.2768598  
2013    3.880595458 5.093861168 5.581054333 13.46712894 10.75883057 14.32018705 12.8004113
2014    3.704607564 4.553207543 5.579917866 13.06164254 11.40024489 11.72714768 10.48395416
2015    4.172712226 5.575909066 5.599194095 13.02779828 12.03512165 12.50450009 12.53610883
2016    3.923721987 5.114003872 5.592298604     14.37830603 13.66334668 12.46776302
2017    4.199701662 5.209742712 5.587904286 14.23295248 13.5470283  14.31672959 14.50842956
2018    3.842899789 5.366232079 5.583735373 14.37107164 16.24971535 16.22325711 13.11337662
2019    4.193109197 5.218867245 5.592100707 14.13660894 15.26532847 15.54818    14.13108974
2020    3.881220078 4.994767886 5.594671332 10.59726867 12.80355967 14.47961213 12.26830666
2021    4.129839662 5.413975796 5.588821077
```

Comment: Welcome to CV.  I formatted your question. For future refererence I used the {}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about coding, not statistics, and so strictly speaking should be on https://stackoverflow.com/ and not here, but I can say this: the model `lm(y ~ x)` has two coefficients, the intercept and the slope (the effect of x). This is why you have two rows for each model.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that.